# Chart.js 2.2.1 - Chart doesn't render correctly before resizing

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

Like the title says, my charts don't render correctly:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBtdG.png)

here's my html:

```
<div ng-show="!(loading)">
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body" >

                <canvas id="base"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My charts are set to responsive in the options. Any suggestions would be apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue one time and the issue occurs because the element in which i puted my "chart" didn't exist on load . Check if your HTML is ok before putting your chart in it.

By The way, do you have more code to provide us? it'll be more easy to help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function that will actually run through and build your chart after the parent element has been rendered. You can do this by wrapping that function inside a document ready tag. That way when the document is ready the function will fire and build the chart once it knows the parent elements size.

Something like this:

```
function buildChart(){
//Build your chart here
}
```

And then wrap it like this:

```
$(function(){
 buildChart()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what happened, but it's working correctly now... I just cleaned some files from older versions. Didn't have time to try any of your solutions, but thanks for answering!